# Positive type function on open subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, topological-graph-theory

Let $\phi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. We say that $\phi$ is positive type if $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} c_i\bar{c_j}\phi(g_{j}^{-1}g_i)\geq 0$ for all $n \in N, c_i \in \mathbb{C}, g_i \in G$.

Let G be a topological group and H be an open subgroup of G and $\phi$ be the characteristic function on H. Can you help me prove that $\phi$ is positive type?

Comment: It's the positive definite function associated to the representation of $G$ on $\ell^2(G/H)$ relative to the Dirac function $\delta_{x_0}$, where $x_0$ is the base-point of $G/H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\phi(g_{j}^{-1}g_i)=1 \Leftrightarrow g_{j}^{-1}g_i \in H$$

On $G$ define $g \equiv h \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}h \in H$.

Now, let $n \in N, c_i \in \mathbb{C}, g_i \in G$.

Split $g_1,.., g_n$ into left cosets. To make this clear, denote by $H_1,.., H_k$ the **non-repeated** left cosets $g_1H,..., g_nH$ (i.e. $H_i \neq H_j$ if $i \neq j$ and $\{ H_1,.., H_k\}= \{ g_1H,.., g_nH \}$).

Then
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} c_i\bar{c_j}\phi(g_{j}^{-1}g_i)=( \sum_{l=1}^{k}\sum_{g_i,g_j \in H_l} c_i\bar{c_j}\phi(g_{j}^{-1}g_i))+ ( \sum_{1 \leq l \neq  m\leq k}^{k}\sum_{g_i \in H_l, g_j \in H_m} c_i\bar{c_j}\phi(g_{j}^{-1}g_i)) \\
=( \sum_{l=1}^{k}\sum_{g_i,g_j \in H_l} c_i\bar{c_j})+ ( \sum_{1 \leq l \neq  m\leq k}^{k}\sum_{g_i \in H_l, g_j \in H_m} c_i\bar{c_j} \cdot 0)
= \sum_{l=1}^{k}\sum_{g_i,g_j \in H_l} c_i\bar{c_j} = \sum_{l=1}^{k}\left| \sum_{g_i \in H_l} c_i \right|^2 \geq 0 
$$